# Извлечение диаграмм UML из кода

Tags: c++, uml

Пишу курсач) Знаю что UML и написание кода - не в такой очередности выполняются. Но просто нет времени сначала делать UML, а затем приступать к кодированию, ибо это ОЧЕНЬ долго и может быть полезным при больших проектах. Поначалу так и начинал делать, а потом понял, что в процессе реализации вся логика может 10 раз поменяться и диаграммы надо будет переделывать (структура базы уже 2 раза менялась). Поэтому решил не терять время и написать сначала прогу, а затем заняться диаграммами.

Пишу в Visual Studio 2010 на С++ под MFC. Единственное, что знаю - это 2 пути извлечения диаграмм классов - "реконструировать" в Visio и получить диаграмму встроенными средствами Visual'а.

Что еще и как можно извлечь? Может программами или просто как-то пробежаться по вызовам и получить, например, диаграмму последовательностей.

П.С. Преподавателю ОЧЕНЬ важны эти диаграммы и их правильное составление. Он даже вряд ли программу будет смотреть. Но UML - точно.

Comment: разве студия не генерирует по коду сама?

Comment: @Gorets Может быть. Тогда как это сделать?

Comment: > нет времени сначала делать UML, а затем приступать к кодированию, ибо это ОЧЕНЬ долго

> в процессе реализации вся логика может 10 раз поменяться и диаграммы надо будет переделывать

Вспоминаются две пословицы: "время - деньги" и "скупой платит дважды".

Comment: Это не тот случай. Прогу-то я допишу через дня 2 и останется по коду сделать UML. Есть что посоветовать?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff657806.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Enterprise Architect, проверено работает. Диаграмму классов формирует на основании кода. Во вкладке Code, есть команда для выбора (импорта) файла, после чего автоматом программа сформирует диаграмму. С диаграммой можно работать. а при желании сохранить. Триал версию можно установить, а при желании найти в инете)

Answer (score 1):

2 лучших на мой взгляд способа:

- Полную йерархию классов (для С++ достаточно подробную), а так же другую полезную документацию можно получить с помощью [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/). Инструмент бесплатный, открытый и очень полезный в случае когда хочется иметь свежую документацию к постоянно изменяющемуся проекту.
- html страницу на которой можно динамически генерировать UML диаграммы можно получить с помощью [Doxygraph](https://code.google.com/archive/p/doxygraph/). Инструмент открытый и основан на Doxygen. Пример можно посмотреть [тут](http://doxygraph.sourceforge.net/doxyviz/graphviz.html).